# Downloading and viewing a log file in python

Tags: python, url, download

I'm using python 3.4.3 and I'm trying to write a program which downloads a file using an existing URL (let's call it URL1).
I don't care about the file though I want to get any lof file (e.g how much bytes were downloaded, how long did it take).

Which commands/libraries should I use? 
Tried to do it with urllib.request.request but got stuck with no further clue.

Answer (score 0):

Before someone closes the question, I would recommend the requests module.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

To determine the information about how long it takes to download, you actually have to download the material.

For downloading I would use [urllib2.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and just `read`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

bytes_read = len(urlopen(someurl).read())
```

For timing you can use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: @Galpo That is just a newer version. I am still using urllib2 most of the time. You should not worry about it for what you want to do.

Comment: how can i work with urllib with the newest python version ? the compiler does not allow me to do such thing

Comment: @Galpo I don't see your problem. `urllib.request` has a `urlopen` that works (at this level) in the same way as the `urlopen` in `urllib2`. I updated the code